# Cycle through windows without focusing on them

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-management

I'm on elementary OS `5.1.4` Hera and use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut to cycle through open applications. This cycles through applications by bringing each window into focus (foreground).

However, I want to be able to cycle through applications without focusing on them, a la Mac style cycling. Is there a shortcut, setting or app that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean cycle thtough applications?

Comment: @MAJacob Correct! Cycle through applications. Making an edit for clarity.